# Precision Problem in pgfmath

Tags: tikz-pgf, bar-chart, pgfmath

When i make the difference between two bar, the difference shows only fixed value. i want precision value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\newcommand{\PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU}[2]{\begingroup%
%\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu,/pgf/fpu/output format=fixed}%
\pgfmathtruncatemacro{#1}{#2}%
\pgfmathsmuggle#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfplotstableread[header=true]{
        dir   L    R
        Jan 66.2 121
        Feb 42.9 55.7
        Mar  45.1 73.2
        Apr  51.7 75.9
        May  65.4 88
        Jun 40.4 80.7
        Jul 65.5 86.9
        Aug  70.7 99.1
         Sep  59.2 91.9
        Oct 84 110
        Nov 80.5 117
        Dec  77.3 90
    }\honeydat
    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\honeydat}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\numrows}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
        \begin{axis}[width=18cm,ybar,ylabel=Cost (Dollars),
            axis x line*=bottom, % show bottom x-axis and dont remove tick marks
            %axis y line=none,
             %yticklabels={cents},
        %y tick label style={text width=1.3cm,align=right}
            scaled y ticks = true,
            enlarge x limits={abs=0.5cm},
            bar width=13pt,
            xtick={0,...,11},
            xticklabels={Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec},
            ymax=140,
            ytick={0,20,...,140},
            nodes near coords,
            nodes near coords style={
                anchor=south,
            },
            every node near coord/.append style={
                yshift=-13pt,
                font=\tiny
            },
        ]
        \addplot[draw=black,fill=gray!20] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=L] \honeydat;
         \addlegendentry{FLAME}
        \addplot[draw=black,fill=gray!70] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=R] \honeydat;
        \addlegendentry{Traditional}
        \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{0,...,\numrows}{%
         \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{L}\of{\honeydat}%
         \edef\myL{\pgfplotsretval}%
         \pgfplotstablegetelem{#1}{R}\of{\honeydat}%
         \edef\myR{\pgfplotsretval}%
         \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mysign}{sign(\myR-\myL)}
         \ifnum\mysign>0
          \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mydiff}{\myR-\myL}
          \edef\temp{\noexpand\path[fill=orange!20] (axis cs:#1,\myR)
            rectangle ([xshift=-13pt]axis cs:#1,\myL);
            \noexpand\draw[densely dashed,orange!80!black] 
            (axis cs:#1,\myR) -- ++ (-13pt,0pt) 
                node[pos=0.5,above]{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=2]{\mydiff}}
              -- ([xshift=-13pt]axis cs:#1,\myL);          
            }
         \else
          \PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mydiff}{\myL-\myR}
          \edef\temp{\noexpand\path[fill=green!20] (axis cs:#1,\myL)
            rectangle ([xshift=13pt]axis cs:#1,\myR);
            \noexpand\draw[densely dashed,orange] 
            (axis cs:#1,\myL) -- ++ (10pt,0pt) 
                node[pos=0.5,above]{\noexpand\pgfmathprintnumber{\mydiff}}
              -- ([xshift=13pt]axis cs:#1,\myR);           
            }
         \fi
         \temp}
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you truncate the result.

Replace `\PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mydiff}{\myR-\myL}` with `\pgfmathsetmacro{\mydiff}{\myR-\myL}`. So is `\PgfmathtruncatemacroFPU{\mydiff}{\myL-\myR}`.

[image]